# Llamar Formularios en Visual Studio 2015 desde un MenuStrip

Tags: visual-studio-2015, formularios, menú

Me gustaria saber como llamo un formulario desde un MenuStrip sin cerrar el formulario donde esta el Menu
Los codigos que e usado son de Visual Studio 2008 y no me sirven para Visual Studio 2015

Comment: En que lenguaje de programación

Answer (score 0):

Pon la propiedad isMdiContainer = true del formulario principal

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo suelo hacer así:

```
Dim f as New Nombredelformulario
f.ShowDialog()
```

Luego al final para liberar recursos pongo bajo del *ShowDialog*

```
f.Dispose()
```